# I got this error while working in JSON part 1 sample xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am getting the following error:

> Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x6a2b1a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}

Please tell me what this error means?

Comment: we can't help like this, please post some code to be able to examine your issue.

Comment: Paste the json string that you want to pars. I think that your string is not jason valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is returned by SBJSON when the first non-whitespace character is different from

```
{ [ " f(alse) t(rue) n(ull) - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and it means that the JSON data you’re trying to parse is not valid.<sup>1</sup> As @Nirmal suggested, use http://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON data. For a description of what valid JSON should look like, see http://json.org and [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627).

<sup>1</sup>The error also means that the first non-whitespace character is different from `+`, which is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate your JSON object [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/), I guess there is some issue with the JSON output..

Comment: Thank you Nirmal. I modified the output.